# How to write object to and read object from file using servlet

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, java-io

i am trying to write objects of a POJO class to a file and read them with the same Servlet with the Java serialization methods. I have the POJO in a public class and the writer and reader codes in two other public classes. I then accessed both the writer and reader methods in a servlet. The problem is that only the last object written to the file could be deserialized. It seems previously written objects were overwritten. See the codes below please.

The POJO class:

```
public class Comment implements Serializable{
    private  String name;//max 24 digits
    private  String date;//6 digits
    private   String email;//max 24 digits
    private  String comment; //to be stored into database as clob no max
    private  String id;//auto generated

    public Comment(){}

    public Comment(String id){

    this.id = id;
    }

     public Comment(String name, String email, String comment){
    this.name=name;
    this.date=date;
    this.email=email;
    this.comment=comment;
    }

     public Comment(String name, String date, String email, String comment){
    this.name=name;
    this.date=date;
    this.email=email;
    this.comment=comment;
    }

    public Comment(String name, String date, String email, String comment,           String id){
    this.name=name;
    this.date=date;
    this.email=email;
    this.comment=comment;
    this.id=id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

     /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the comment
     */
    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    /**
     * @param comment the comment to set
     */
    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    Comment myComment;

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    { 
    return 31 + id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {


        if(obj instanceof Comment){
            Comment another = (Comment)obj;

            if(this.getId()==another.getId()){

                return true;
            }

        }
            return false;
    }

    public String toString(){
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    return sb.append(name).append(",").append("     ").append(date).append(",").append(" ").append(comment).append(",").append("     ").append(id).append(",").append(" ").append(email).toString();
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

The writer class:

```
public class ObjectStreamWriterExample {

    public void write(Object obj){

        File outFile = new File("out.txt");

        try(ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));){

        List <Object> commentList = new ArrayList<>();

        commentList.add(obj);


        for(Object list : commentList){

        objectOutput.writeObject(list);
        //System.out.println("good ok now");
        }
        }catch(IOException io){
            System.err.println("An Error occured :");
            System.out.println(io.getCause());
        }
    }


    }
```

Reader class:

```
public class ObjectStreamReaderExample {

    public List <Comment> read( String inFile){

        Comment comment = null;
        List <Comment> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try(ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(new     FileInputStream(inFile));){

            while(true){

                try {

                    comment = (Comment)oi.readObject();

                    list.add(comment);

            break;

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }catch(EOFException eof){
                    System.err.println("Reached End of File");
                    eof.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }catch(IOException io){
            System.err.println("Error :");
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The servlet:

```
public class ObjectStreamExample extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

         ObjectStreamWriterExample oswe =new ObjectStreamWriterExample();

        oswe.write(new Comment("Omobolaji", "omo@javanice.net", "omo is   commenting"));
        oswe.write(new Comment("Omobolaji", "omo@javanice.net", "omo is commenting again"));
        oswe.write(new Comment("Omobolaji", "omo@javanice.net", "omo is commenting again hhhhh"));

        ObjectStreamReaderExample osre = new ObjectStreamReaderExample();

        List <Comment> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list = osre.read("out.txt");

        for(Comment myList : list){
        out.println(myList.getName() + "<br> ");

        out.println(myList.getEmail() + "<br> ");

        out.println(myList.getComment() + "<br> ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: Well, probably because you only write one comment to the file each time you call `write`.

Answer (score 0):

No mystery. Every time you call `write()` you create a new file and write one object to it. You also create a completely pointless list, add the one object to it, iterate the list, once, of course, and write the one object you find in it to the file. Next time you call `write()`, you do all this nonsense again. Result: one file, with one object in it.

You need to completely reconsider all this. You can't append to object stream files without special measures. You should:

1. Create the file by opening it for output.
2. Write as many objects to it as you wish.
3. Close the file.
4. Open the file for input.
5. Read objects from it until you reach end of file, which is signalled by, err, an `EOFException`.
6. Close the input file.

**OR**

1. Create a list.
2. Append as many objects as you wish to the list.
3. Open the file for output, serialize the *list*, close the file.
4. Open the file for input, deserialize *one* object, the *list*, and iterate it to recover all the original objects, and close the input file.

NB

- Object streams are not text, and should not be saved in files with the `.txt` extension.
- The fact that you're in a servlet is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, ill try all your suggestions. Don't mind me, I'm a bloody beginner.

Comment: Your suggestions worked when the objects were added directly but the file seems to be temporary. when the program is run again with new objects added, the old data could not be read.

Comment: i want to be able to save form input to file each time a user fills the form and i also want to be able to read the inputs of all users once the page remain loaded